# Renaming the WooCommerce Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Previously I suggested renaming the `wordpress.com` tag to `wordpress.com-hosting`. I consider that a successful change :)

I suggest making the following additional rename:

- `woocommerce` to `woocommerce-offtopic`

Alternatively, `plugin-woocommerce-offtopic` or `offtopic-woocommerce`

Comment: I believe the issue someone would need to stay ontop of the tag to make sure it doesn't get recreated, as there's no locking tags. Maybe it can be added as a tag synonym or vice versa?

Comment: People would just pick `woocommerce` instead as they don't want their question closed

Comment: I'm onboard but we would need to collectively watch for any tag recreations so that we can nix them before it gets out of hand. I'm also not sure of the implications should we ever decide to bring 3rd party on topic.

Comment: Why would someone tag their question with a tag named `woocommerce-offtopic`?

Comment: they wouldn't :) some people write WC questions on the assumption it's on topic because there's a tag, and some people don't read our scope and would see the `offtopic` while tagging. Said users would then realise it isn't appropriate for the site and go elsewhere, or be curious and read the description that sends them to the .org support forum

Comment: We could leave `woocommerce` as synonym, so it can't be recreated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've renamed the tag to `woocommerce-offtopic` and created a synonym to prevent the original being recreated. Hopefully this improves things a little, if not we can undo the change.

Comment: What happens now is that people are just not using the tag, even when the question is about Woocommerce.